# How threads work

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem understanding how threads work:

```
class ThreadTest implements Runnable{ 
    synchronized void methodA(long n){ 
        for (int i=1;i<3;i++){System.out.print(n+" "+i)} 
    } 

    public void run(){ 
        methodA(Thread.currentThread.getId()); 
    } 

    public static void main(String ... args){ 
        new Thread(new ThreadTest()).start(); 
        new Thread(new ThreadTest()).start(); 
    } 
}
```

As I currently understand, because `methodA` is a synchronized for loop in this method, it must finish before next thread calls this method -- so the result must be like `4-1 4-2 5-1 5-2...`

Is it possible to have a result like `4-1 5-1 5-2 4-2`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it possible to have result like 4-1 5-1 5-2 4-2.?

It is possible.

> If yes how?

You are using the `this` reference as the object which is locked by `synchronized`. Since you've got two distinct instances of `ThreadTest`, each method locks its own instance and mutual exclusion is not achieved.

So, what you must understand is the semantics of `synchronized`: there is always a clearly defined object involved whose *monitor* is *acquired*. Basically, that object notes which thread has acquired its monitor and will allow only the same thread to re-acquire it; other threads will be put on hold until the monitor is released. Any other object, naturally, has nothing to do with this and its monitor is free to be acquired by any thread.

A `synchronized` method implicitly uses `this` for the lock. What you can do for your example is declare a `static final Object lock = new Object();` and use `synchronized(lock)` in your method.

Comment: "each method locks its own instance" -- \*facepalm\* how did I overlook this?

Comment: @JanDvorak It has happened to me on other occasions :) It's not hard to miss it.

Answer (score 1):

you can  have results 4-1 5-1 5-2 4-2 .Also you may get 5-1 5-2 4-1 4-2 as result since you can not guarantee which thread will run.Thread start will only put that thread in runnable list.Thread scheduler will decide which thread to run